# Is there a way in Matlab where I can generate a list of folders that have a particular folder in them?

Tags: list, matlab, indexing

I'm working in Matlab and I have a directory of patients. Each patient has a folder with their ID("Patient ID"), and in that folder, there is a folder for the date("Date"). In the date folder, there are more folders that contain various information(for example CT_Image, PET_Image, MR_Image). The scheme is something like this:

Patients> Patient_ID> Date> MR_Image

Is there a way in Matlab where I can generate a list that tells me which "Patient ID" has a particular folder and which ones do not? So instead of manually checking all the patients in the "Patient" Folder for an "MR_Image" folder, I can just check the results of the list?

Comment: Do you mean you want to do something like `ls Patients/*/*/MR_Image`?

Comment: Yes, this is almost exactly what I want. I was hoping for an output that would give a boolean or something similar regarding all the patients. ex. Patient 1:TRUE, Patient 2:FALSE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Here some code to scan you patients data.

Brahim 

function ListPatientsData(strPatients, strDataType)
if(nargin == 0)
    clc
    clear
    close all    
    strPatients = pwd;
    strDataType = 'MR_Image';
end
disp(['root folder is ' strPatients])

hPatientIDs = dir(strPatients);

nNbPatientIDs = size(hPatientIDs, 1);
disp(['nNbPatientIDs = ' num2str(nNbPatientIDs)])
disp(' ')

for nPatient = 1:nNbPatientIDs
    hPatientID = hPatientIDs(nPatient);
    if(hPatientID.isdir)
        strPatientID = hPatientID.name;
        
        if(strcmp(strPatientID,'.'))
        % Do nothing 
        elseif(strcmp(strPatientID,'..'))
        % Do nothing 
        else 
            disp(['Patient_ID = ' strPatientID])
            
            hDates = dir([strPatients '/' strPatientID]);
            nNbDates = size(hDates, 1);
            % Minus 2 coz '.' and '..'
            disp(['nNbDates = ' num2str(nNbDates-2)])
            
            for nDate = 1:nNbDates
                
                hDate = hDates(nDate);
                if(hDate.isdir)
                    strDate = hDate.name;
                    
                    if(strcmp(strDate,'.'))
                    % Do nothing 
                    elseif(strcmp(strDate,'..'))
                    % Do nothing 
                    else 
                        disp(['strDate = ' strDate])
                        
                        hDataTypes = dir([strPatients '/' ...
                                          strPatientID '/' ...
                                          strDate]);
                        nNbDataTypes = size(hDataTypes, 1);
                        % Minus 2 coz '.' and '..'
                        disp(['nNbDataTypes = ' num2str(nNbDataTypes-2)])
                        
                        for nDataType = 1:nNbDataTypes

                            hDataType = hDataTypes(nDataType);
                            if(hDataType.isdir)
                                strDataType = hDataType.name;
                                %
                                if(strcmp(strDataType,'.'))
                                % Do nothing 
                                elseif(strcmp(strDataType,'..'))
                                % Do nothing 
                                else 
                                    disp(['strDataType = ' strDataType])
                                                                        
                                    hDataFiles = dir([strPatients '/' ...
                                          strPatientID '/' ...
                                          strDate '/' ...
                                          strDataType '/*.*' ]);
                                    nNbDataFiles = size(hDataFiles, 1);
                                    % Minus 2 coz '.' and '..'
                                    disp(['nNbDataFiles = ' num2str(nNbDataFiles-2)])
                                    
                                end
                            end
                        end
                    end
                end
            end
            disp(' ')
        end
    end            
end
```